# EVM RPC Test Suite to test proper implementation of JSON-RPC Specifications

Tags: evm, json-rpc, testing

I'm looking for an existing and still supported EVM RPC Test Suite to test if a custom RPC implementation is in line with the official JSON-RPC Specifications.

I'm not looking to build my own suite, I merely want to compare my results with other RPC implementation for compliance.

Ideally, I would supply an RPC https address and a mnemonic phrase to a config file and run all tests to observe the discrepancies.

Comment: I am also looking for this, did you find anything?